# Cannot run dotnet test with new microsoft docker images

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, .net-standard

Since [Microsoft moved all of their images](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-syndicates-container-catalog/) to their own container registry, their previous images no longer exist. My project was specifically using `microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk` to build and test our dotnetstandard2.0 class libraries. Our test project is targeting `netcoreapp2.0`

However, with the new Microsoft image repository, this image no longer exists, and instead, there are only SDK images for [3.1 and 5.0](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/). Using the 5.0 sdk image I was able to get `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` to work. However, for some reason, `dotnet test` fails with the following error:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.10 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
```

I'm not really sure why `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` work but `dotnet test` does not and I really don't want to install SDK 2.0 into this container just to workaround this. Are there any better solutions?

For more specifics, [this merge request](https://github.com/Subterfuge-Revived/Remake-Core/pull/69) shows the failing pipelines and the current dockerfiles, and the `master` branch shows what we had before.

Comment: You say that only your test project targets netcoreapp2.0. Can you change that, so it targets net5.0 and see if that helps?

Comment: As far as I know Microsoft removes the images for the 2.0 version because that version is unsupported

Comment: This was announced as part of the deletion of unsupported versions from the Docker Hub registry: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2848. .NET Core 2.0 has been out of support since Oct 2018. It is highly recommended to upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Haven't had time to test this but I will try making my test projects target net5.0 and see if that works!

Comment: Update: I installed Net 5.0 and updated my test projects to target netcoreapp5.0 and this seems to have worked. Thank you :)